# How to join two tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables.

Table 1 has a `Filename` column which contains values like this:

```
AV_SDBT_NonPay_SXM_PRE15_INV_20170712_results_20170716.txt  
data_20170715.dat.zip.pgp  
demo_20170715.dat.zip.pgp  
gm_SiriusXM_COI_Export_20170715000255.dat.gz.pgp  
gm_SiriusXM_COI_Export_20170716000247.dat.gz.pgp  
gm_unsubs_20170715.dat.gz.pgp  
IBS_Number_Skill_Assignment-en-us_2017-07-16T020008476Z.csv  
IGN_Action_Det_20170716.txt
```

And table 2 has a `File_Frmt` column which contains this data:

```
gm_SiriusXM_COI_Export*.pgp  
Contest_Sweeps*  
fiddemo*  
IWCO_SXM_EST_IN_HOME*.gpg  
demo*.pgp  
IWCO_IWCO*Processed*.gpg  
*SDBT_NonPay*
```

Is there a way to  match these two tables with `Filename` and `File_frmt`?

If the `filename` contains `file_frmt`, then match else not match.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `INNER JOIN` with `LIKE` and `REPLACE` will do it.

Create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T1 as TABLE
(
    Filename nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES
('AV_SDBT_NonPay_SXM_PRE15_INV_20170712_results_20170716.txt'),
('data_20170715.dat.zip.pgp'),
('demo_20170715.dat.zip.pgp'),
('gm_SiriusXM_COI_Export_20170715000255.dat.gz.pgp'),
('gm_SiriusXM_COI_Export_20170716000247.dat.gz.pgp'),
('gm_unsubs_20170715.dat.gz.pgp'),
('IBS_Number_Skill_Assignment-en-us_2017-07-16T020008476Z.csv'),
('IGN_Action_Det_20170716.txt')


DECLARE @T2 as TABLE
(
    File_Frmt nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES
('gm_SiriusXM_COI_Export*.pgp'),
('Contest_Sweeps*'),
('fiddemo*'),
('IWCO_SXM_EST_IN_HOME*.gpg'),
('demo*.pgp'),
('IWCO_IWCO*Processed*.gpg'),
('*SDBT_NonPay*')
```

The query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM @T1 as t1
INNER JOIN @T2 as t2 ON t1.FileName LIKE REPLACE(t2.File_Frmt, '*', '%')
```

Results:

```
Filename
gm_SiriusXM_COI_Export_20170715000255.dat.gz.pgp
gm_SiriusXM_COI_Export_20170716000247.dat.gz.pgp
demo_20170715.dat.zip.pgp
AV_SDBT_NonPay_SXM_PRE15_INV_20170712_results_20170716.txt
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/RSCDI17940)

BTW, if your `file_Frmt` also contains `?` as a placeholder for a single char (like in Microsoft search patterns), you can replace that with `_`.